# Meteor including bootstrap and jQuery

Tags: meteor

I get an error as soon as I add jQuery and Bootstrap. The three files that I add are

```
1) a_jquery-1.11.2.min.js // so that it is processed before 'b' in bootstrap
2) bootstrap.min.css
3) bootstrap.min.js
```

and they are located in `/lib`.

If I add bootstrap without jQuery, I get an error saying that Bootstrap needs jQuery. After I add jQuery I get the following error messages.

```
/Users/username/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.cbg34i++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
            throw(ex);
                  ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'createElement' of undefined
    at jb (app/lib/a_jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2:7547)
    at app/lib/a_jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2:22045
    at app/lib/a_jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2:22746
    at c (app/lib/a_jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2:207)
    at app/lib/a_jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2:212
    at app/lib/a_jquery-1.11.2.min.js:6:3
    at /Users/username/my_app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:205:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/username/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.cbg34i++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
```

Does anyone know what I am missing?

EDIT: I also have a question about including the stylesheets. I include a CDN bootstrap in `/client/views/layout.html` but as soon as I delete the importing line and save a local `bootstrap.min.css` file in `/lib` the styles start breaking. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/lib` folder is for shared code, putting client-side frameworks in it will cause you a lot of trouble since Meteor will try to run it on the server too (and miserably fail at finding a `window` object). Place any client-only code in the `client` folder instead.

Plus, I would suggest [taking a look at packages](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=bootstrap) rather than doing it yourself, a lot of people have already done what you're going through.

If you want to have local style sheets, either put them in the `client` folder (loaded immediately) or in the `public` folder (for delayed loading via an import). More about special folders in the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp).

Answer (score 1):

You can't put them in /lib since anything in there is also loaded by the server. /client/lib would be okay.

Note also that you don't need jQuery, that comes by default (it's used by Blaze).

Finally, I'd recommend using a bootstrap package. If you use [this one](http://nemo64:bootstrap) then you'll by able to make use of all the mixins and also change the base varaibles cleanly. See [this article](http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/meteorjs-and-twitter-bootstrap---the-right-way) for more information.